# TSI engine, shaking at idle

Tags: engine, vw, idle, shaking

I have Vw Scirocco (2011) 1.4 Tsi 160 hp with DSG, my car started to shaking at idle (RPM is stable) at uphill really bad that I got rid of my kidney stones. It is shaking at idle whether it is warm or not and the shaking is not sensible at straight or downhill roads.

I'm going to list what I tried;
-Compression is checked, 4 cylinder is ok.
-Checked for bad engine mounts, left one changed (did not fixed the shaking)
-There is no any error codes checked via vagcom

Comment: I'm guessing if one of the coils (this is a coil-on-plug design right?) was not firing you would get a trouble code?  That's an idea tho.  Have you looked at all the plugs?

Comment: Yes, I'd have an error code and there is no misfiring at all. All coils are perfectly working.

Comment: It was worth asking... I had a coil fail on a TSI, and had similar issues, but I also had codes.  How long has this been going on?  Could it be bad fuel?  Does it happen when you unplug the MAF sensor (will force the fuel management to a default mode)?

Comment: I tried every available fuel in my town, nothing changed and I have this issue about 15.000km.. but I did not even think about MAF sensor, I'll try to unplug it and see what changes. If I'm not wrong, MAF sensor would tell me if there is any air leakage in pipes so if I disable it and the engine turns out to be fine, should I search for pipes right ? (sorry about my language)

Comment: It will tell you that _something_ related to the fuel/air ratio is off.  Could be a restriction in the air filter, bad MAF, or something related, but it would at least point your troubleshooting in a new direction.

Comment: thanks for giving me direction, I'll check it at weekend.

Comment: record and post some data if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally find the reason why my car is shaking at idle when the car at uphill. It was a piston failure and repair cost is around 2000$ and also that failure damaged compressor( which is combined with supercharger ) that needs to be replaced with a brand new one and it cost around 450$.

My total repair cost was like 3000$. So, I decided to sell my car.

If you have a tsi engine and face a problem similar to this one, It will be definitely a piston issue.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! Any idea what caused the piston failure?
These engines are quite notorious for problems with excessive timing chain wear, with can cause al kinds of (potentially expensive) problems.

Comment: The previous owner used the car without engine oil, so that caused the piston cracks and when I bought the car those cracks were filled with hardened oil. When the engine gets hot, hardened oil particles liquefied that caused the piston works in an unusual way. That also caused the compressor/supercharger sometimes work with expected power and it ended up not getting its gears in a correct time when the gas pedal is pushed so it started to fail. In a short explanation, please check your engine oil level every day.